# Help creating a filter

Tags: formula

I want to create a filter that will give me the difference between Close date and Open date. I have no clue where to start.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Is it about building a report or custom development ?

Comment: Trailhead is usually the right place to get started, but we can't refer you to an appropriate module without more clarity on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Shamina this is for building a report.

Comment: You'll want to search Salesforce Trailhead for building formulas and creating report filters, perhaps as two separate topics.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a formula field of type number and decimal place zero.
Use below formula

`IF (IsClosed, Round(ClosedDate - CreatedDate, 0), Round(NOW() - CreatedDate, 0))`

Use this formula field as a filter in your reports.